# Get key value from multidimensional array not working

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, controller

I am trying to get a value from a multidimensional array by its name 'code'. When I dump and die the first way it returns the correct value. When I then want to use that in the code, it gives the error "Undefined index: code". I also used the array_column way, that dd an empty array.

The code that should get the correct $code:

```php
foreach ($houses as $house) {
    $code = $house['code']; //Returns correct value in a dd, not in the code
    $code = array_column($house, 'code'); //Returns empty array in dd, later gives the error Array to string conversion in the file_get_contents
    $a = file_get_contents('some-url' . $code . '/surveys');
    $a = json_decode($a, true);

    $surveys = $a['surveys'];
    $completedSurveys = $a['surveysCompleted'];

    $done = 0;
    $ndone = 0;

    foreach ($completedSurveys as $complete) {
        if($complete) {
            $done++;
        } else if(!$complete) {
            $ndone++;
        } else {continue;}
    }
}
```

`$house` dump:

```
array:30 [
    id: ''
    project: integer
    city: ''
    streetName: ''
    houseNumber: ''
    code: ''
    fullStreet: ''
    forms: array:1 [
        0: integer
    ]
]
```

`$code` dump

```
$house['code']: "AB12-CD34-EF56-GH78"
array_column($house, 'code'): []
```

I would like to know the solution to this so that I can use the $code in the url to get the correct things back from the api.

Comment: array_column returns an array and you are using as it as a string in file_get_contents

Comment: can you show dump of all `$houses`? seems like at least one of them hasn't `code` field. and get rid of `else {continue;}`, cause it will never execute

Comment: @RomanBobrik Sorry I cannot, but you are correct $houses is an array of 60(0-59) and only the first three have 'code'

Comment: @coder yes I realized that, thats why I got the error Array to string conversion. That is also why that is not the best solution

Comment: So start with `if(isset($house['code'])) { …` inside your loop then …

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column on your entire array, not the sub-arrays.

```
$houses = 
[
    [
        'code' => '23',
        'city' => 'Dublin'
    ],
    [
        'city' => 'Canberra'
    ],
    [
        'code' => '47',
        'city' => 'Amsterdam'
    ]
];

var_export(array_column($houses, 'code'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '23',
  1 => '47',
)
```

You could then do something along these lines.

```
$get_survey = function ($code) {
    if($response = file_get_contents("http://example.com/$code/surveys"))
        if($json = json_decode($response, true))
            return $json;
};

$completed = [];
foreach(array_column($houses, 'code') as $code) {
    if($survey = $get_survey($code)) {
        // survey count calculation.
    } else {
        $completed[$code] = null; // failure to get survey data.
    }
}
```